# stuck of start mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

```
    2017-03-01T00:51:32.863-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2017-03-01T00:51:33.271-0500 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory 'D:/mongo/data/diagnostic.data'
2017-03-01T00:51:33.284-0500 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017
2017-03-01T00:51:33.391-0500 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50501 #1 (1 connection now open)
2017-03-01T00:51:33.394-0500 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50502 #2 (2 connections now open)
2017-03-01T00:51:33.399-0500 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50503 #3 (3 connections now open)
2017-03-01T00:51:33.401-0500 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50504 #4 (4 connections now open)
2017-03-01T00:51:33.406-0500 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50505 #5 (5 connections now open)
2017-03-01T00:51:33.418-0500 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50506 #6 (6 connections now open)
```

When I start the mongoDB, the command line pop up these things, how could I fix it? I have tried delete the data folder...

Comment: What do you wanna do exactly?

Comment: start the mongoDB my code is shut down due to this problem, mongoDB cannot start completely...

Comment: It seems fine to me. Did you try to execute "mongo" from another instance of terminal?

Comment: Thanks bro, I suppose maybe there are some wrong with my code actually, when I git reset, things turn to be well again